# Convert a Jupyter notebook to html output in native Python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I know I can call

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html notebook.ipynb
```

from shell, or do a system call from Python:

```py
import os
os.system('jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html notebook.ipynb')
```

But having to do this with a system call when an `nbconvert` module is available in native Python seems very odd!

I want to write native python to execute and convert a iPython notebook to an html file.
I studied the [official documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html) a little but couldn't piece things together.
My questions are:

1. Is there an example to convert notebooks to html in native Python?
2. Is there a compelling reason not to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I figured out after some trial and error:

```py
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
from nbconvert import HTMLExporter

# read source notebook
with open('report.ipynb') as f:
    nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

# execute notebook
ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=-1, kernel_name='python3')
ep.preprocess(nb)

# export to html
html_exporter = HTMLExporter()
html_exporter.exclude_input = True
html_data, resources = html_exporter.from_notebook_node(nb)

# write to output file
with open("notebook.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html_data)
```

Admittedly a lot more work than a single `os.system` call, but I'm surprised there are so little native python examples out there...

Comment: I had to set the encoding of the HTML-file to UTF-8: "with open("output/MEB_SKI_26_analysis.html", "w", encoding="utf") as f:"